# How do I use variable in ionic template that is initialized at ngOnInIt() method within subscribe() method?

Tags: angular7, ionic4, templating

I've declare a class variable (property) and it is initialize at ngOnInit() method. 
The value that i have initialize is received from Route.paramMap.subscribe() observable.
The initialization is done inside subscribe() method.
Code Given:

.ts file:

```
export class EditOfferPage implements OnInit {
  place: Place;
...
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {

    this.place = this.placesService.getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId'));
```

.html (template file)

```
<ion-back-button
        [defaultHref]="'/places/tabs/offers/' + place.id"></ion-back-button>
```

At template I get and error of Un-Defined **place** variable.

Cant Post Error Img [Error Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIC1c.png)

This is obviously because the subscribe() method run separately (thread) and template is loaded before the initialization is done.

i have tried initializing at declaration and **it works.** but **I want to know better option / way to do it.**

```
export class EditOfferPage implements OnInit {
  place: Place = new Place('', '', '', '', 0);
```

I want program to wait for value to be initialize at subscribe and then only load the template.
Please suggest better options.

Answer (score 0):

Use ? for undefined object:

```
<ion-back-button
    [defaultHref]="'/places/tabs/offers/' + place?.id"></ion-back-button>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work in          `[routerLink]="['/', 'places', 'tabs', 'offers', 'edit', place?.id]"`

Comment: This should work.. which version  of angular you are using.. could you please share your project file ?